# laptop battery usage with AC supply

Tags: battery-life

Does the laptop battery get affected by A.C. supply? 
Does the life of the battery gets affected if run our laptop continuously on A.C. power? 
All the laptops run on A.C. power when getting fully charged up and still connected to supply mains.
Thank you

Comment: Depends on the battery type.  Some batteries develop a memory of the charge level and if always at full or near full charge, they will not delver power much below that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were times when batteries worked with the current passing through them even when the AC adaptor was plugged in and the battery was fully charged. Later the smarter things came, and the system ran the current around the battery when it is fully charged. Even though any battery will lose 20% its capacity every year even if it is constantly full charged. So if you are working always from AC and thinking about to disconnect your battery, charge/discharge the battery to about 50% and then take it away. Store it in the dry and cool place.

Answer (score 2):

If you remove the battery but your laptop is still connected to a working AC socket, your laptop will continue to run. This means that working on AC power actually replaces the battery completely.

However, it is a good practice to keep batteries in cool place (i.e. a fridge) in order to maximize the battery life. Although I am not entirely certain it help in newer batteries, it may still have a small impact on the shelf life of the battery: most of the manufactures recommend storing batteries in cool places, so it can't harm. **Important note:** if you decide to keep the battery in your refrigerator, make sure it is protected from wetness!

Also, depending on your battery type (Lithium, for example), you may be able to find some more specific recommendations over the internet.

Answer (score 2):

If your battery type is li-on (modern notebook, and I mean 5-8 years from now) it's recommended that the battery does not empty. When leaving a battery alone it will lose charge overtime, so maintaining it charged is better to prolong it life.

When the ac adapter is connected the notebook will draw energy from the adapter and not the battery, it will only charge it if the requires. So it is recommended to leave the battery connected and always you can use the ac adapter.